# Execute code on app exit

Tags: python, events, kivy, exit

A game-app stores the user's progress every few seconds to a file. However, if the user exits the app before that data is stored, some of it might not be stored.

Is there a way to run specific code as soon as the user tries to close the app? Something like an `on_exit` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [App](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App) class there's an on_stop event that can be used, or directly use the [on_stop](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.on_stop) method (EventHandler).